# Using HTML in multiple components

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it is possible to use a HTML of one component in another component ? If I go with `Selector` then it will render with TS Component also (i.e) functionality. I just that particular HTML page to be used multiple places? any ways?

Comment: Components' use is to use code written once in several places. If you need to re-use a piece of code, then that piece of code should be a component. Please don't treat HTML as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible you can create a typescript file which will export that template

```
export const HTMLTemplate = `here will be the template`
```

And the you will change `templateUrl: 'url'` to `template: HTMLTemplate`
and import the `HTMLTemplate` from file you have created.

**Detail:**

You can create `typescript` file let's call it `HTMLtemplate.ts`

In that file you will add this line

```
export const HTMlTemplate = `<div></div>`;
```

Instead of `<div></div>` you can use your template you want to share between components.

As a next step you will go to the component where you want to use the shared code and you will change it from this

`@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.scss']
})`

to this

`import {HTMLTemplate} from 'where the HTMLtemplate.ts is';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  template: HTMLTemplate,
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.scss']
})`

Comment: Interesting. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: You can create a component for that, and wherever you want to use that static content, you can use that component.  

One issue which I found in your solution is that, you can give only one url in `templateUrl` property. If you want to use that static text in your component then it will be difficult.

Comment: I have added some details to the answer.